# Which should I use, pear MDB2 or pear DB_DataObject when I use MySQL when I can not use PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pear, mdb2

Almost all of free web hosting server,

you can not use PDO + MySQL.

They lack PDO drivers.

So I am considering to select

pear MDB2,

or DB_DataObject.

Which do you reccomend to me?

Give me your opinions!

Answer (score 2):

I would actually recommend using the [Mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli) functions if you can. They are fast, well-documented and well supported by the php community at large.

If you are looking for a more robust database abstraction layer, I would first suggest that you look at any of the excellent library's out there like DataMapper, or Propel or Doctrine, or even using the necessary portions of a framework like Zend. As further note, I've used Adodb in the past, but haven't seen much support for it recently.

Answer (score 0):

I've used MDB2 quite a bit but have found the built-in mysqli functions to be fast and easy-to-use, plus they can integrate easily into a roll-your-own db abstraction layer.

Answer (score 0):

[ADOdb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) is also good.

The PHP version currently supports an amazing number of databases, thanks to the wonderful ADOdb community: MySQL, PostgreSQL, Interbase, Firebird, Informix, Oracle, MS SQL, Foxpro, Access, ADO, Sybase, FrontBase, DB2, SAP DB, SQLite, Netezza, LDAP, and generic ODBC, ODBTP. The Sybase, Informix, FrontBase and PostgreSQL, Netezza, LDAP, ODBTP drivers are community contributions.

Answer (score 0):

DB_DataObject depends on MDB2, so you have to have it anyway.

The question is : do you need just bare database independence or more advanced ORM (that's DB_DataObject).

I'd suggest you stick with MDB2 since you seem confused about this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **DB_DataObject** with **MDB2** without problems.